# Display specific divs or content based on browser language?

Tags: javascript, html, localization

I'm creating a pretty simple site of maybe 4 pages, that I want to be available in English, French, and Portuguese.

Is there a way, with javascript, to detect the browsers language, then only display certain divs that correspond to their language?

For example, if their language is French, instead of showing `<div id="footer_en">` it will use `<div id="footer_fr">`?

Answer (score 5):

The usual approach is to keep the languages separate (one HTML file per language for example) and send the content back in the language they want. You could try to parse the [Accept-Language header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.4) and send back the closest match; you'd probably want to include a language selection widget of some sort as well.

If you really want to do this on the client with JavaScript then you should:

- Set the [`lang` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/dirlang.html#h-8.1) on each piece of content (or wrapper `s).
- Grab the language from `navigator.languages`, `navigator.language`, or `navigator.userLanguage` (check them all, `languages` is the latest, `language` should be everywhere, and `userLanguage` is AFAIK for older IEs) and have a suitable default in hand just in case.
- Then show everything whose `lang` matches the language and hide everything whose `lang` doesn't match.

For example, if you have this HTML:

```
<div lang="en" class="wrapper">
    <h1>English</h1>
    <p>Here is some English content.</p>
</div>
<div lang="fr" class="wrapper" style="display: none;">
    <h1>Française</h1>
    <p>Voici le contenu en français.</p>
</div>
<div lang="pt" class="wrapper" style="display: none;">
    <h1>Português</h1>
    <p>Aqui você encontra o conteúdo Português.</p>
</div>
```

And then some JavaScript (I'll use jQuery as that's my weapon choice):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var known = { en: true, fr: true, pt: true };
    var lang  = ((navigator.languages && navigator.languages[0]) || navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage || 'en').substr(0, 2);
    if(!known[lang])
        lang = 'en';
    // Find all <div>s with a class of "wrapper" and lang attribute equal to `lang`
    // and make them visibile.
    $('div.wrapper[lang='  + lang + ']').show();
    // Find all <div>s with a class of "wrapper" and lang attribute not equal
    // to `lang` and make them invisibile.
    $('div.wrapper[lang!=' + lang + ']').hide();
});
```

Here's a live example: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/kwcfL67a/

If you keep the show/hide logic in a separate function that takes a language argument then it would be pretty easy to provide a language selection widget of some sort too.

You could also use a class for the language if that's easier to work with using your JavaScript tools but leaving the `lang` attribute around would be a good idea.

---

Thanks to [coliff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1694672/coliff) for the `navigator.languages` update that recent versions of Chrome seem to need.

Comment: This solution no longer seems to work in Chrome. It does work in Opera and Firefox though. Would be great if you could take a look and see if you can fix. :-)

Comment: What specifically doesn't work @coliff? The `navigator` properties?

Comment: The jsfiddle you provided shows in French when browser preference is set to French in Firefox and Opera on Windows desktop as well as iPhone  (works correctly), but in Chrome it always shows in English even if browser language preference set to French.

Comment: @coliff `navigator.language` seems to be set properly for me in Chrome so I don't know what's wrong for you. Sorry.

Comment: I found the solution; you need this:
var lang  = (navigator.languages && navigator.languages[0] || navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage || 'en').substr(0, 2);

Here is an updated working Fiddle with the change: http://jsfiddle.net/coliff/7ojeuaxc/

Comment: So they've thrown `navigator.languages` into the mix @coliff ?

Answer (score 2):

Start with this:

```
var userLang = (navigator.language) ? navigator.language : navigator.userLanguage;
userLang = substr(1,2);
```

Then set `<body class="userLang">`, which I leave up to you as I don't want to assume you are using a specific javascript library or framework.  Next up you can use CSS to show, hide, or do what ever you want on you divs.  For example if `fr` is your default:

```
#footer_fr { display: block; }
#footer_pt { display: none; }
#footer_en { display: none; }
body.pt #footer_en { display: none; }
body.pt #footer_fr { display: none; }
body.pt #footer_pt { display: block; }
```

I'm not sure the above is perfect CSS, but you get the idea.

Answer (score -1):

Combine the CSS :lang() selector: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#lang (nevermind that it is the CSS2 rec and not CSS3, the :lang() selector remains the same) with dynamic loading of CSS or DOM manipulation.

Comment: My understand of the above is this will only work if the `lang` is explicitly set on the `body` tag.  I don't think this is auto set by the browser is it?